# How to unpaired/Disconnect connected/Paired devices in BLE?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want my app remove paired bluetooth devices. Because if device are paired , these devices are not come under while scanning the device and unabl to sychn with other. I tried CBCentralManager cancelPeripheralConnection, but it doesn't work. they're still paired.I can handle it programmitically but main problem is that they are not showing up in scanningPeripheal devices?

Comment: You can't modify pairing programatically.  Only the user can clear a pairing through settings. Pairing shouldn't affect your ability to discover and connect to peripherals though.

Comment: if i connect the device once..it will not comes under scanning(the list i want to show the scanned devices but if that device connect once it will not scanned that again)..this is the main problem i am facing.can you help me out?

Comment: What device do you have?  I have test with LightBlue beans and pairing makes no difference to discoverability

Comment: using polar devices.if once i connect that devices it will not comes under scanning devices.

Comment: Once you have paired with it, you shouldn't need to scan for it anyway. You can just connect.

Comment: actly what i have to do is like i have different users and different devices.once its scanning done...one user select their devices.next time the device needs to be disconnect and another select that devices and accordingly data reflect with respect to that user.for that reason i needs to disconnect and reconnect manually.